# State not appearing, updating or being passed to value of checkboxes from semantic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

**EDIT: Require checkbox to be checked is resolved, just cant work out how to get the checkbox values into the email.**

The aim: *Pass the value of* *state.TNC* and *state.promos* *into the* *emailjs.sendForm*.
The form should return *alert "You need to accept Terms and Conditions before proceeding.*

I am lost for words as to what I need to google to find a resolution.

Here is my code that I thought was going to do that for me.

```
sendEmail = (e, props) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.TNC !== true) {
      return emailjs
        .sendForm("test", "testTemp", e.target, "user_EPYkKnHwljQTCbuiyfJkzO7YD")
        .then(
          (result) => {
            alert("Email sent successfully!");
            e.target.reset();
          },
          (error) => {
            alert("Email send failed... :( I had one job...");
          }
        );
    } else {
      return alert(
        "You need to accept the Terms and Conditions before proceeding."
      );
    }
  };
```

The code for the two checkboxes, (I have tried them with and without the *value={this.state.TNC}*)

```
<Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field>
            <Checkbox
              label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
              required
              control={Checkbox}
              data="TNC"
              onChange={this.onToggle}
              value={this.state.TNC}
            />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <Checkbox
              label="Send me occasional updates and promotions"
              defaultChecked
              control={Checkbox}
              data="promos"
              value={this.state.promos}
              onChange={this.onTogglePromos}
            />
          </Form.Field>
        </Form.Group>
```

Here is the full code, and you can find a semi-functional version of the form at https://test.ghostrez.net

```
import React from "react";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input, TextArea } from "semantic-ui-react";

export default class ContactUs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      TNC: false,
      promos: true,
    };
  }
  onToggle = () => {
    const TNC = !this.state.TNC;
    this.setState({ TNC });
  };
  onTogglePromos = () => {
    const promos = !this.state.promos;
    this.setState({ promos });
  };
  sendEmail = (e, props) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.TNC !== true) {
      return emailjs
        .sendForm("test", "testTemp", e.target, "user_EPYkKnHwljQTCbJkzO7YD")
        .then(
          (result) => {
            alert("Email sent successfully!");
            e.target.reset();
          },
          (error) => {
            alert("Email send failed... :( I had one job...");
          }
        );
    } else {
      return alert(
        "You need to accept the Terms and Conditions before proceeding."
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.sendEmail}>
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field
            id="firstName"
            control={Input}
            label="First name"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            required
          />
          <Form.Field
            id="lastName"
            name="lastName"
            control={Input}
            label="Last name"
            placeholder="Last name"
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field
            id="Email"
            control={Input}
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="joe@schmoe.com"
            onChange=""
            required
          />
          <Form.Field
            id="Phone"
            control={Input}
            label="Phone"
            name="phone"
            placeholder="0469 420 689"
            required
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Field
          id="Message"
          control={TextArea}
          label="Message"
          name="message"
          placeholder="Message"
          required
        />
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field>
            <Checkbox
              label="I agree to the Terms and Conditions"
              required
              control={Checkbox}
              data="TNC"
              onChange={this.onToggle}
              value={this.state.TNC}
            />
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <Checkbox
              label="Send me occasional updates and promotions"
              defaultChecked
              control={Checkbox}
              data="promos"
              value={this.state.promos}
              onChange={this.onTogglePromos}
            />
          </Form.Field>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Field
          id="Submit"
          control={Button}
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          positive
          content="Submit"
        />
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

**Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way you have written the logic

`this.state.TNC !== true`, what does this equate to? `false !== true` which is `true`, hence it goes in the if block. I think what you want is `if(this.state.TNC)`, i.e. if it's true, then go in the if block.

Also, your Email field throws an error because it's `onChange` is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the requiring TNC to be checked. 
do you know why the checkbox values arent being picked up and passed into the email?